# How does doctrine handles unchanged field when updating an already existing entity

Tags: php, doctrine, mariadb

Supposing I have an entity mapped to a `MariaDB` database table with the following fields: `ID`, `firstName` and `lastName`.
This entity has been loaded from the database in the PHP object and I execute the following code

```php
/**
 * $myEntity is the entity and $em is the entity manager
 * $myEntity->getFirstName(); Would be John
 * $myEntity->getLastName(); Would be Doe
 */

$myEntity->setFirstName("Bob");

$em->persist($myEntity);
$em->flush();
```

Will this result in the following query:

```
UPDATE `table`SET `firstName` = 'Bob' WHERE `ID`= "x"
```

Or the following query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `firstName` = 'Bob', SET `lastName` = 'Doe' WHERE `ID` = 'x'
```

More generally: How does Doctrine handles unchanged fields, and what is consired as "unchhanged" ? Same value, no variable assignation, something else?
I have searched in the Doctrine documentation and on Google but I have found nothing about this question.

I am asking because I have an entity which is, obviously, bigger than the one in the example (35 columns, including 2 `TEXT` columns) and often only one or two columns are updated at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JoshuaRaposa's answer was correct, but it seemed to have been extracted out of thin air. I ran my own tests by enabling logging on the database.

Executed code

```php
/**
 * $myEntity is the entity and $em is the entity manager
 * $myEntity->getFirstName(); Would be John
 * $myEntity->getLastName(); Would be Doe
 */

$myEntity->setFirstName("Bob");
$myEntity->setLastName("Doe"); // Setting the last name to the same value as it currently is
$em->persist($myEntity);
$em->flush();
```

Resulting query

```
UPDATE `table`SET `firstName` = 'Bob' WHERE `ID`= "x"
```

## Conclusion

- Doctrine only updates modified columns to their new values without including unmodified columns in the query
- Setting the column to the same value it was before is not detected as value change by Doctrine, which means that you can set all your columns every time, massively simplifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine only updates what actually changed, so your first scenario will happen.

Comment: I would have appreciated your answer to be sourced. I ran my own tests by loggin all the queries to the database and confirmed your answer.